# Facebook Realtime Subscription to individual wall posts?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I've set up a Realtime Subscription for object `user` and fields `feed` and I am receiving realtime posts from Facebook.

I'm not interested in getting an update about every little thing that happens on every user's feed though. Is there a way to subscribe to just a single post?

My app is making a post to several user's feeds and then I would simply like my app to monitor anytime that specific post is liked or commented on.

Is it possible to subscribe to a certain post?

Answer (score 0):

In current implementation of Realtime Updates seems like it is impossible, because you can not subscribe to specific object. Furthermore updates information that you receive doesn't contain any identifying information like post ID.